# How can I calculate normals of closed shape in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, normals

I am trying to write my own mesh importer for my own file format. In my file format there is no normal data. So I am trying to calculate normals of a close shape and apply those normals to mesh.

My solution is calculating a normal vector for every face of geometry and create a raycast from middle of these faces in the direction of normal vector. If that raycast hit something (another plane) it means this direction is inside. In that case I flip normal, If it does not hit something I leave it that way.

While I wrote a function with this logic, normals don't change at all.

```
        function calculateNormals(object){

            for (var i = 0; i < object.geometry.faces.length; i++) {
                var vertices= object.geometry.vertices;
                var face=object.geometry.faces[i];



                var a=vertices[face.a];
                var b=vertices[face.b];
                var c=vertices[face.c];

                console.log(face.a+" "+face.b+" "+face.c+" "+face.normal.z);
                console.log(face);
                console.log(face[4]);

                var edge0=new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
                edge0.subVectors(a,b);

                var edge1=new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
                edge1.subVectors(b,c);

                var planeNormal=new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)
                planeNormal.crossVectors(edge0,edge1);

                // console.log(planeNormal);

                //Raycast from middle point towards plane nrmal direction
                //If it hits anything it means normal direction is wrong
                var midPoint=calculateMiddlePoint([a,b,c]);
                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(midPoint,planeNormal);

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([object]);
                if(intersects.length==0){
                    console.log("Normal is true");
                    face.normal=planeNormal;
                }else{
                    console.log("Normal is wrong, you should flip normal direction, length: "+intersects.length);

                    console.log("Old face");
                    console.log(face.normal);

                    var newNormal=new THREE.Vector3(-1*planeNormal.x,-1*planeNormal.y,-1*planeNormal.z);
                    console.log(newNormal);
                    face.normal=newNormal;



                    console.log("new face");
                    console.log(face.normal);
                    console.log(face);
                }

                object.geometry.faces[i]=face;


                // console.log(object.geometry.faces);

            };


            return object;


        }
```

Comment: Have you checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886818/issue-with-custom-geometry-and-face-normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matey makes a good point. The winding order is what determines the face normal, meaning which side is considered "front." Vertex normals are used for shading (with `MeshPhongMaterial` for example). If your vertex normals point in the opposite direction from your face normal, you'll end up with unintended results (anything from bad shading to a totally black face).

All that said, `Geometry` has helper functions for calculating normals.

[`Geometry.computeFaceNormals`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry.computeFaceNormals) (based on winding order)

[`Geometry.computeFlatVertexNormals`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry.computeFlatVertexNormals) (sets a vertex normal to be the same as the associated face normal)

[`Geometry.computeVertexNormals`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry.computeVertexNormals) (sets a vertex normal to the average of its surrounding face normals)

Once you've computed the normals, you could make a second pass to try and correct them, either by re-ordering the vertices (to correct the face normal), or by re-calculating the vertex normals yourself.

Comment: thanks, your post made me understand how three.js calculates normal

Comment: The Geometry class is deprecated and the BufferedGeometry doesn't have a computeFaceNormals function.
So I am struggeling with that a little bit.

Comment: @Ralf If you need assistance with the current implementation, please post it as a new question and we'll be happy to take a look.